# Mysql setting a record as deleted or archive

Tags: mysql, record

Is there any way to omit some records in mysql select statement and not deleting them?
We can easily add a column for example `deleted` and set it to 1 for deleted ones and keep them but the problem is that we have to put `where deleted = 1` in all queries.
What is the best way to keep some records as an archive?

Comment: You could to it with a trigger of some condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how many tables you have and how much data you want to store, but a solution could be this one:

- You create a tblName_HIST table for each the tables (tblName) you want to keep the virtually deleted data
- ***Optional***: Add a DELETED_DATE column to keep track of the date the record was deleted.
- You add a Trigger on the tblName tables that ***AFTER DELETE*** statement ***INSERT*** the record in the tblName_HIST table.

This will allow you to keep the Queries and the DB tables made since now without modify them that much.

Comment: I think this is the best way!But you should do it BEFORE DELETE not AFTER That. Thanks you ALL

Comment: It depends.. usually i delete and then insert the records but with SQL Server DBMS. I'm not that expert in MYSQL. :)

Comment: :I did find a problem with this answer!Foreign Keys will fail!

Comment: Hoping that you DB schema is not that much complex, you should first move the child records that of course should be marked as DELETED since you are deleting a parent record and then move the record you are deleting to keep the integrity of your data.